# ID of last inserted field

Tags: mysql

I have a table DEVICEDETAILS whose primary key is DEVICEID. I would like to get the ID of the field that was last inserted. The last_insert_id() does not work as the primary key is not AUTO_INCREMENT.

Thanks in advance to Stack Overflow People

Comment: What stops you from making the AUTO_INCREMENT field the PK while making your "real" PK a UNIQUE KEY ?

Comment: Actually when I delete a record , i need to reuse the same id. for this purpose , i idnt use AUTO INCREMENT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if it is not auto_increment I assume that you have just inserted the record using deviceid so surely you already know it.

Comment: I got the deviceID from a function and should i use the same function to get the last inserted Id?is there no other way?

Comment: @SiniSalim why not assign that returned value to a variable first and then insert it into database?

Answer (score 1):

True. It will not work on primary key that isn't Auto-Incremented. How about this?

```
SELECT MAX(DeviceID) FROM DeviceDetails
```

**OR**

What `DeviceID` did you inserted? `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

If the primary key is not `AUTO_INCREMENT`, then you should know the value you inserted.

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_insert_id()
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html